# laptop wont come up from suspend/sleep mode

Tags: suspend, 15.10

On a HP Probook 470 g2 laptop with 15.04 suspend worked fine. I updated to 15.10 and when the computer goes to sleep mode, after that it wont come up from sleep mode . Leds remain on and fan is working. I have to restart the laptop in order to get it to work, I can see that some other people had the same problem, but I see no solution. 
Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: What type of graphics card is on the laptop?

Comment: AMD Radeon R5 M255